# Which Python PEPs deal with code style?

Tags: python, coding-style, pep

Which Python PEPs deal with code style?  I am aware of two: [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and [PEP 257](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/).  Are there any others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list is huge!!
Check official python Peps here
http://www.python.org/dev/peps

Answer (score 2):

P     7  Style Guide for C Code                                  GvR